# Download part of html as a template in c# mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 C# project and in one of the pages, i'm showing a list of HTML email templates so the user can see how the email templates are and be aware of what is being send to the customers.
Now, what i want is a button in each template that allow me to download that template in one `.html` file.
How is this possible?

Comment: did you mean download the email template files as html and it is physically placed on server?

Comment: No.. i mean, on the page, have a button that allow the user of the website to download that template as an `.html` file.

Comment: OK, so my question is that templates are in which format ? are these available on server physically?

Comment: What i mean is that i need a button on the page that allow me to download a portion of HTML code that is ON that page to a `.html` file

Comment: OK, pick the portion do you want to download onButton click and download as html using Response.Redirect and dont forget to set the content type "text/html"

Comment: Can you post a sample so i could understand better?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fc = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Path/To/File.html");
    return File(fc, "application/octet-stream", "download file name.html");
}
```

This will change the way the client will process it and will assume it's a downloadable file.

Tested on IE11 and FF.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i came with this solution:

```
public ActionResult DownloadTemplate(string templateName)
        {
            using (var service = new MyService())
            {
                var template = service.GetEmailTemplateByName(templateName);
                string attachment = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}_TEMPLATE.html", templateName);
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                Response.Write(template.Body);
                Response.End();
                return new EmptyResult();
            }
        }
```